# Set checkbox label to right side or fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This is the code for a standard checkbox:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
        <legend>Agree to the terms:</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" />
        <label for="checkbox-1">I agree</label> 
</fieldset>
```

How can I set the label (text) of a checkbox to the right side or to a fixed "px" position?

Something like `align-right` or `right: 50px`

Comment: Should'nt it already be on the right side -> [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXjga/) ???

Comment: Sry i should say i work with jquery mobile and the checkboxes look like this: [Checkbox](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html) . You right the text is always on the right side of the checkbox but i mean on the right side of the "button"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `classname` or ID for the label like the following:

```
<label for="checkbox-1" class="chkbox">I agree</label>
```

Then add css rule for the class,

```
 .chkbox {
   padding-left: 10px;
   font-weight: bold;
 }
```

You can give padding, border or whatever style u like for the label.

Demo: [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sriganesh/DxY9x/)

Answer (score 6):

just add style  in required label

```
<label for="checkbox-1" style="float:right">I agree</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have this controls in html file

```
<label for="2">Laparoscopic surgery</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="question" value="14" class="clickable" id="2"  />
```

It's enough to do this in css:

```
.clickable{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
$(function(){ 
 $('label[for="checkbox-1"]').css({right: 50});
});
```

**OR**

```
$('label[for="checkbox-1"]').css({'margin-left': 50});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XXjga/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Fix the width of the input field and label and float them.

For example:

```
input {
   width: 200px;
   float:left;
}

label {
   width:300px;
   float:left;
}
```

And clear your floats afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Float the checkbox to the right and the label to the left, and set the label position to absolute.

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="question" value="14" class="clickable" id="2"  
    style="float: left;"/>
    <label for="2" style="float: right; position: absolute;">Laparoscopic 
    surgery</label>
```

If you just put the label text to the right of the box without a label, it will not cause the checkbox to be checked when clicked.